# How to make label editable on a button click and show keyboard to type text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I would like to have an "edit" button in order to be able to change the text of my label.

[image]

I need to use the keyboard to write the new text. I mean I know how to make a button with `label.text = "new label"` but I want to give the possibility to the user to change the label text with his keyboard.
I tried with a text view but we can not (I didn't found any solution on my own and on internet) make a button that could redirect us into the text view to change the text.

I work a lot with storyboard so if you have a storyboard solution it would be perfect but I would understand Objective-C and Swift too :)

Thank you!

Edit: Thank you Henrique da Costa, solution is to put `[TextView becomeFirstResponder];` in the button action. `TextView.becomeFirstResponder()` in Swift.

Comment: You press the button? The text view become first responder and ready for editing. And your editing button become a save button. You edit in the textview, you press the save button. You pass the textview's text to the label. Will this meet your requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a textField with a placeHolder "User information" and no user interaction enabled:

[image]

and then you can create and Action for your editButton and inside the function you can

```
textField.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

and this will open the keyboard for the user to type his information.

Comment: I need multiple lines of information but I will try with textView.becomeFirstResponder !

Edit: it works with `[TextView becomeFirstResponder];` in the button. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UITextField` instead of a `UILabel` and then toggle the `enabled` property.

Comment: I needed several lines so it doesn't fit with my work but this would work too! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UITextField` in the `StoryBoard` and wire it to the `Controller` class. Now modify the `Edit` button action as shown

```
yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This will open up the keyboard and help your controller to receive the typed in text. Now you can opt to show or hide the `UITextField`. If it is hidden you may update the label with each characters instantaneously and if it is shown you can modify the label text when user hits `return` or so. Use `hidden` property to hide `UITextField` in `viewDidLoad`

```
yourTextField.hidden = true
```

Now set the `Controller` to receive the `UITextField` delegate properties in `viewDidLoad`and extend the controller class with `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

To modify label text instantaneously `override` the method

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

and to modify label when user hits `return` on keyboard, `override`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

Comment: I needed several lines so it doesn't fit with my work but this would work too! Thanks

Comment: to add multiple lines to UILabel, set `yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

Comment: Yeah I know but that's a textfield, not a label ;)